# Place braces around multiples lines of <p> tags using sed, and stop when it reaches <h1>, <h2>, <h3>

Tags: awk, sed

I have an HTML file with `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, and `<h3>` tags. I need to make the `<p>` tags to be in braces, and if they’re subsequent `<p>` tags on each line, the braces should begin at the first instance, and the closing brace at the closing `</p>` tag, even if it’s a few lines down.

Example content:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```

Desired output:

```
{<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
{<p>Paragraph 4</p>}
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```

Note in the desired output that the closing brace is when the lines swap to an `<h1>`. The number of subsequent `<p>` tags can be anywhere from 2, to 20.

My current sed solution is just replacing opening `<p>` tags with an open brace, and closing `</p>` tags with a closing brace.

```
sed 's|<p>|{|g' | sed 's|</p>|}|g'
```

Unfortunately this does it line by line, and what I need is to match multiple lines, and ignore closing/opening tags if they're followed by another `<p>` tag so that they're lumped together.

I've been unable to find a solution for this yet. I'm happy to use perl, awk, sed, whatever gets the job done. It just seems like I need a way to recognise this particular pattern.

Edit: Ed Morton's solution below worked perfectly for me.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Why isn't `<p>Paragraph 1</p>` mentioned in any output for example? Why should Paragraphs 3 and 4 be combined in the output instead of 2 and 3 or 1, 2, and 3? Please [edit] your question to simplify the output (we don't need to see 20 fields per line of output to be able to help you - ask for help to produce output with, say, 3 or 4 fields) and post the actual expected output. I edited your pipeline to start each sed on a new line to make that part more legible.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, you're right. I've edited my question to remove unnecessary information, and tried to clarify.

Comment: Much better, thanks, You should put the code you tried back so you don't get downvoted for not showing your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^<p/ {
    ps = (ps == "" ? "" : ps ORS) $0
    next
}
ps != "" { print "{" ps "}"; ps="" }
{ print }
END { if (ps != "") print "{" ps "}" }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
{<p>Paragraph 4</p>}
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```